# How to get the images into a grid view in android by using Volley?

Tags: android, json, android-volley, android-gridview

I already tried many examples.I found Keys are same in that but I got a new Json in which  keys are different for Image Urls. I want to retrieve the images in a gridview.I need logic please help to my project.Thanks in Adavnce.The example link is https://dzone.com/articles/download-and-display-image-in-android-gridview.

My JSON structure is

```
  {
"profilePic": [
    {
        "a0": "http://wedicons.com/admin/images/uploads/d4c5543b-Desert.jpg",
        "a1": "http://wedicons.com/admin/images/uploads/fbbadae6-Hydrangeas.jpg",
        "a2": "http://wedicons.com/admin/images/uploads/31914e88-Jellyfish.jpg"
    }
],
"status": 1
}
```

Comment: use picasso for this

Comment: Use Glide . Read http://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/

Comment: Try this perfect one : https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-custom-gridview-images/

Comment: I agree with you But I want to go through a0,a1,a2... like that so many .I don't know how many images are there.It want to retrieve all Images.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Picasso Library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for loading image into ImageView.

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://my.url.to/image").into(imageView);
```

and add it in `build.gradle` file in dependencies module;

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
```

For Example in your case for **a0**:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://wedicons.com/admin/images/uploads/d4c5543b-Desert.jpg").into(imageView);
```

Comment: I got it .But It is possible when I know how many images are there.If there are n number of images How can I write?.Thanks for reply

Comment: yuppp...you have to simply pass image url in Picasso syntex.

Comment: Manually I can do it.But if the user upload another image .I can't write manually everytime.Am I right.Is there any logic to do dynamically.

Comment: No,u can't write manually everytime. You have to fetch JsonArray from response using for loop and get JsonObject of image url and set in ImageView using Picasso.

Comment: I tried but I am getting error in getting keys in for loop.Help me in that.